# Given the wave equation, show $u_{yw}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation: $\alpha^2 u_{xx}=u_{tt}$.
I am told to let $y=x-\alpha t$ and $w=x+\alpha t$ and use chain rule but I'm not confident in my attempt.

I got $x=\frac{y+w}{2}$ and $t=\frac{w-y}{2\alpha}$. Found $u_{yw}(x,t)=\frac{\alpha^2u_{xx}-u_{tt}}{4\alpha^2}$, then used then wave equation to conclude $u_{yw}=\frac{0}{4\alpha^2}=0$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Thank you! How would I derive my x and t values? I had help from my professor with this part, but she did not tell me how she got them. @CheeHan

Comment: It comes from solving the system of equations $y = x - \alpha t$ and $w = x + \alpha t$.

Comment: Duh, I don’t know why I didn’t think of that. Thank you! @CheeHan